# Как обрезать миллисекунды в SELECT MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не могу понять как обрезать миллисекунды в выводе datetime.

```
tmp.card_type,
  carriers.carrier_name,
  customer.surname + ' ' + customer.name AS customer_name,
  tmp.save_time --поле datetime
  into #trans
```

На выходе получаю

> 2018-11-09 04:33:28.127

Comment: обычно это делают на клиенте. Есть ф-ция форматирования, можно так  `select convert(char(19), current_timestamp, 120)` функция convert обрежет по макс к-во символов (19)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datatime, tmp.save_time, 120);
SELECT cast(convert(char(19), tmp.save_time, 120) as datetime);
```

[datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[SQL Server CONVERT() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)

Comment: просто поле берется из tmp. И так будет ошибка

Comment: укажите правильно откуда берется дата, и все будет норм

Comment: Так указываю. No column name was specified for column 50 of #trans

Comment: Все вопрос, походу, решился добавлением имени AS

Comment: ну вот и все...)